# Ordering SQLite table by sum of two columns

Tags: sqlite

I have a database that has two integer columns, and I'm trying to find a way to select the top 'x' amount of rows with the highest sums of these two columns. I'm trying to eliminate the need of creating a third column that stores the sum of the two, unless there's a way to to automatically update this column every time one of the other two are altered. I'm using SQLite by the way, as I know there are some slight differences here and there between SQL/SQLite syntax.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```sql
SELECT a, b
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY a + b DESC
LIMIT :x
```

should do it.